# Stacking 2 or more progress bar in one bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

As title, and the example for it is like

[image: Stacking Progress Bar]

Where the 80% refers to the green bar and 90% refers to the darker grey bar.. this is just example anyway, because due to some problem with my coding, i cannot show the 90% on the right hand side of the bar, and thus i just edit it on Paint instead..

Currently i'm using the following code to implement this bar

HTML:

```
<div id='progBar'>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:
    progress:

```
function (percent, current,  $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    var currentBarWidth = current * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 2000);
    $element.find('div div').animate({ width: currentBarWidth }, 2000);
}
```

CSS:

```
#progBar {
    width: 275px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    margin: 2px 0 0 4px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #000;
}

#progBar div {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 25px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
    width: 0;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

#progBar div div {
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    background-color: #b4d134;
    margin-top: 6px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
}
```

The first div bar with id Progbar is the whole progress bar, and the second < div>< /div> block refers to the 1st progress bar (darker grey color), and the 3rd < div>< /div> block refers to the green bar.

So far i found the code working for me, but the problem here is that, when i tried to show the percentage on the right end side of the progress bar (the 90%), it just wouldn't show. I can pretty much guess this is due to my HTML coding where i stack several div block in one line, in which the display follows the order of the div block..

So i want to ask if there is any other way to display my progress bar like above? I don't want to line up 2 different progress bar side by side, i want it to stack on top of each other exactly like how the image above shown.

**EDIT:**
The actual problem is when i try to execute the 2 lines of code below

```
$element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 2000).html(target + "%&nbsp;");
$element.find('div div').animate({ width: currentBarWidth }, 2000).html(current + "%&nbsp;");
```

It shows the current percentage on the left side, but not target percentage on the right side..

Comment: where is the css code?

Comment: edited post - css added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Ok I have edited the code : http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/Aftyj/8/

The code now looks like:

```
var easing = "linear"; //easeOutBounce

function progress(percent, current, $element, duration) {

    var $ref = $('#progressBar1');
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    if ($element.is($ref)) {
        $element.find('div').animate({
            width: progressBarWidth
        }, duration, easing);
    } else {
        $element.find('div').animate({
            width: progressBarWidth
        }, duration, easing).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
    }
}


// Testers
// Tester 1
var currentPercentage1 = 0;
var currentPercentage2 = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (currentPercentage1 < 100) {
        currentPercentage1 = currentPercentage1 + 10;
        progress(currentPercentage1, 0, $('#progressBar1'), 500);
        $('#overlayPercentage').html(currentPercentage1 + "%&nbsp;")
    } else {
        $('#progressBar1').find('div').css({
            width: 0
        });
        currentPercentage1 = 0;
    }
}, 1000);


// Tester 2
setInterval(function () {
    if (currentPercentage2 < 100) {
        currentPercentage2 = currentPercentage2 + 5;
        progress(currentPercentage2, 0, $('#progressBar2'), 100);

    } else {
        $('#progressBar2').find('div').css({
            width: 0
        }).html("&nbsp;");
        currentPercentage2 = 0;
    }
}, 200);
```

And the stylesheet:

```
#progressTable {
    width:400px;
}
#progressBar1 {
    height:44px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color: #292929;
}
#progressBar2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-58px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.progressBar div {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
#overlayPercentage {
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #f11;
    position:relative;
    top:-35px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the demo... but what i meant in my question is that, i want to show 2 types of progress bar stacking together like in the image (the green colored progress bar stacking on top of the dark grey colored progress bar). Also i edited my question again for the actual problem.. please look at it again ><

Comment: Yes exactly this one. Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome, the problem was the fact you were trying to write the percentage in the width-animated `< div>` so it was not possible to right align it on the progressbar container.

Comment: So to fix that, need to create another non-animated layer on top or in between the progress bars? Or at least what i understood from the code you wrote in the fiddle.

Comment: This is one of the solutions indeed. In fact your animation changes the width of the `div` you are trying to set your text into. So this text can't go outside this `div` and then you can't position it as you wanted to.